# Documents are not deleted when using the Javascript APIs deleteByQuery()?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

Using [deleteByQuery()](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-deletebyquery) in the Javascript API I would like to delete some documents from an index called `people`.

It might be important to note that this is version 5.1 in [AWS Elastic Search Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/).

The index mapping looks like this:

```
"people": {
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "parent_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "query": {
          "properties": {
            "match": {
              "properties": {
                "parent_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            },
            "term": {
              "properties": {
                "parent_id": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a search query that is structured as follows:

```
query: {
  term: {
    parent_id: 1
  }
}
```

Responds with:

```
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 10.135444,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "people",
      "_type": "person",
      "_id": "AVp6EDRVm933W5mwl4O9",
      "_score": 10.135444,
      "_source": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "parent_id": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So then using the documentation for the JS API I have created the following:

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')
function deletePeople (parentId) {
  new elasticsearch
  .Client({ host: 'es.host.domain' })
  .deleteByQuery({
    index: 'people',
    type: 'person',
    body: {
      query: {
        term: {
          parent_id: parentId
        }
      }
    }
  }, function afterDeletingPeople (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log("deletePeople :: Error :: ", error);
    }
    else {
      return console.log("deletePeople :: Response :: ", response);
    }
  });
};
deletePeople(1);
```

Which gives a response like:

```
info: deletePeople :: Response ::  { _index: 'people',
  _type: 'person',
  _id: '_delete_by_query',
  _version: 30,
  _shards: { total: 2, successful: 1, failed: 0 },
  created: false }
```

And that looks hopeful but no people are actually removed from the index. I tried to use `match` instead of `term` in the query but that does the same thing.

Could anyone suggest where I have gone wrong here with this as currently my function deletes no people? TIA!

Comment: Looks ok to me, so if you use the exact same body in a search, you get the results, but not in the delete?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: "Delete by Query will be removed in 2.0: it is problematic since it silently forces a refresh which can quickly cause OutOfMemoryError during concurrent indexing, and can also cause primary and replica to become inconsistent. Instead, use the scroll/scan API to find all matching ids and then issue a bulk request to delete them

Comment: @paqash That is correct. If i use the HTTP method: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html it does not delete the items either.

Comment: @Val 5.1 in AWS ElasticSearch Service

Comment: @xecgr I am using 5.1 and its referenced in the the list of AWS endpoints (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es_version_5_1.html) so I don't really understand that, should it not be throwing an error if that was the case? Interesting way to go about it though, thanks for the input!